# Create Tag Cloud with Mongoid Taggable Gem

Tags: acts-as-taggable-on, mongoid3

I want to create a tag cloud just like you can with the acts-as-taggable-on gem, this is an example from the acts-as-taggable-on gem readme:

```
<% tag_cloud(@tags, %w(css1 css2 css3 css4)) do |tag, css_class| %>
  <%= link_to tag.name, { :action => :tag, :id => tag.name }, :class => css_class %>
<% end %>
```

The mongoid_taggable gem using a different method called tags_with_weight which returns an array of tags and the number of times they are used but I dont know how to replicate he tag cloud based on this information.